# Difference between TextInput from "react-native" and "react-native-gesture-handler"?

Tags: react-native

What is the difference between TextInput import from "react-native" and "react-native-gesture-handler"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I too was wondering abou this, but from looking at the source, we can see that the gesture handler version is just a wrapper around the base TextInput. `export const TextInput = createNativeWrapper<RNTextInputProps>(RNTextInput);`

And [online](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/gesture-handlers/create-native-wrapper/) they explain that `createNativeWrapper` as

> "Creates provided component with NativeViewGestureHandler, allowing it to be part of RNGH's gesture system."

So I *think* if you use the wrapped one, it will give you access to all sorts of gestures, like pinching, panning, long press etc that the base input doesn't have